# Не работает vh в Opera Browser

Tags: css, opera

Проблема. Есть div с контентом. Если открывать его на экранах с маленькой высотой, то размер этого блока должен быть на высоту экрана и должна появиться полоса прокрутки. Все работает во все броузерах кроме Opera. Есть ли решение данного вопроса?

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
div{
  max-height: 100vh
  overflow: auto   
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: сделайте так: `div { max-height: 100%;  max-height: 100vh }`

Comment: К сожалению, такой вариант работает как фолбэк. Я его пробовал. Видимо желаемого результата в Opera, можно добиться только через js. Но все равно спасибо!